# Variable result set based

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

Main is a list of widgets with a unique id
Main_Properties is a foreign key from the Main table and a number of possible Properties for each widget
Properties is a table of possible properties.  They contain the following data:

```
Main
id name
1  Widget1

Main_Properties:
id prop  name
1  1     Colour
1  2     Metal


Properties:
prop prop_id text
1    1       Red
1    2       Green
1    3       Blue
1    4       Yellow
1    5       Black
1    6       White
2    1       Gold
2    2       Silver
2    3       Bronze
2    4       Aluminum
2    5       Copper
2    6       Metal
```

If a customer buys 4 of Widget1 then they should only be offered a choice of Red, Green, Blue or Yellow.  If they buy 6 then they would be offered the same plus Black or White. Irrespective of the number they buy they should be offered a choice of Gold, Silver, Bronze, Aluminum, Copper or Metal.

I have two questions:

Is there a better way to structure the tables and
Is there a way in sql that I can limit the choice of colours but not of metal finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd add a column to Main_Properties.

```
Main_Properties:
id prop  name    OfferAllChoices
1  1     Colour  0
1  2     Metal   1
```

I'd then use two parameters within a StoredProc.

```
DECLARE
    @id  INT,
    @qty INT

SELECT
    @id  = 1,
    @qty = 4

SELECT a.name, b.[prop], b.[prop_id], b.[text]
FROM   [Properties] b
JOIN   [Main_Properties] a ON a.prop = b.prop
WHERE 
    a.id = @id AND
    b.prop_id <= CASE a.offer WHEN 1 THEN 99999 ELSE @qty END
```